# Verify that an arbitrary union of members of $\Omega$ belong to $\Omega$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $X$ be the ray $[0, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$, and let $\Omega$ consist of $\varnothing$, $X$, and all rays $(a, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}_{0+}$. I'm trying to prove $\Omega$ is a topology on $X$, but I'm stuck at the idea of how to designate an arbitrary collection of sets for the proof that an arbitrary union of members of $\Omega$ belong to $\Omega$.

I came up with the set $\Omega =: \{\varnothing, X\}\cup\{(a,\infty):a\in\mathbb{R}_{0+}\}$ and I tried stating: For any $A_1,A_2 \in \{(a,\infty):a\in\mathbb{R}_{0+}\}$, we have: that the union of $\varnothing$ with a nonempty set is that nonempty set; $(X \cup A_1) \subseteq X$; and $A_1 \cup A_2$ is identical to whichever of $A_1, A_2$ is larger. Therefore, the condition holds.

The issue is, I'm enumerating (or, I think I am?) all the possible sorts of two types of elements of $\Omega$, but I'm not proving that the union of any possible *collection* of $\Omega$ is in $\Omega$, and I'm not too sure how to proceed. Would anyone have ideas how I can fix the above statement? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(U_i)$ be any collection of sets from the given collection. If one of these sets is $X$ then $\bigcup U_i=X$ and we are done. We can omit all $i$ for which $U_i$ is empty without changing the union. Now we are left with case where  $U_i=(a_i, \infty)$ for each $i$. In this case $\bigcup U_i=(a, \infty)$ where $a =\inf \{a_i\}$.

Comment: thank you very much for the help! this is probably the correct answer, but I have a quick question: don't we need to define the index set $I$ for $(U_i)$?

Comment: @shintuku The index set $I$ is just any non-empty set; I didn't bother to write $i \in I$ explicitly.

Comment: thank you for the help!